# Where can I find the red ? switch block?

Tags: super-mario-64-ds

Where is the ? switch that activates all the red ? blocks in the game?

I'm trying to find it but I haven't been doing well so far.

Comment: unfortunately that's not how this site works.  If someone thinks that your post can be improved they'll edit it to make it better.

Comment: I am sorry, but the way you tagged the question it was bound to be edited anyway...

Comment: @JerryRox That is debatable. The DS tag is used for the DS as a device and its hardware/software. The mario series tag is relating to Mario as a whole, not specific games. On a side note, are you refering to the red `?` blocks?

Comment: Yes. The red ? Blocks

Comment: You may wish to take a minute and consult the [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq) - editing happens to most posts here (both questions and answers!).   People will upvote good content, you don't need to ask them.

Comment: Ok ok I get it! no more comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to the red `?` blocks you have to freelook in the main area of the castle right where you walk in. If you look up while you're standing in the circle you will see a light. Stare into the light and you will get teleported to a new area. Look for the castle with the red switch on it and activate it. This will unlock all of the `?` blocks in the game.

Comment: But I'm trying to. When I stepped in, I pressed the (A) button. It says "A voice from above is saying, 'Hey... Mario...'"